# Display data through linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to display information of food for specific ratings.

```
List<Rating> rates = db.Ratings.OrderByDescending(e => e.Rate).ToList();                    
int i = 0;
foreach(Rating rate in rates)
{
    rates[i].Food = db.Foods.Where(e => e.ID == rate.FID).FirstOrDefault();
    i++;
}
return Request.HttpCreateResponse(rates);
```

The Code above display this information but i want only food object for that rate.

```
"rate": [
        {
            "ID": 15,
            "Rate": 5,
            "FID": 65,
            "UID": 102,
            "Food": {
                "ID": 65,
                "Name": "Grilled chicken",
                "Price": "580",
                "CatID": 75,
                "UID": 101,
                "Date_Time": "2019-04-01T00:00:00",
                "FoodDescription": "Chicken with some oregeno",
                "CookingTime": "25 min",
                "Image": "",
                "Uploadedby": "Hanzala Iqbal",
                "Carts": [],
                "Category": null,
                "User": null,
                "FoodRecommendations": [],
                "OrderFoods": [],
                "Ratings": []
            },
```

I want like this.

```
{
    "ID": 65,
    "Name": "Grilled chicken",
    "Price": "580",
    "CatID": 75,
    "UID": 101,
    "Date_Time": "2019-04-01T00:00:00",
    "FoodDescription": "Chicken with some oregeno",
    "CookingTime": "25 min",
    "Image": "",
    "Uploadedby": "Hanzala Iqbal",
    "Carts": [],
    "Category": null,
    "User": null,
    "FoodRecommendations": [],
    "OrderFoods": [],
    "Ratings": []
},
```

I hope you understand what i am trying to achieve Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code above has no part of displaying and no part of showing the data as json. Please show the code that gives you the json

Comment: Also you are using EF - why perform so many separate linq queries. Use joins or better still set the navigation properties and use `Include`

Comment: I am not sure if I quite understand your problem, but maybe `rates.Select(e => e.Food).ToList()` after your `foreach` is all you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `rates[i].Food = ...` your Rating entity already has a relationship set up to Food. Your code is doing a few things that aren't necessary:

1. Select N+1: By iterating over the Ratings already retrieved, you are going to the DB again for each one to get it's food. This means 1 query to read 200 ratings, and 200 queries to read food's 1 at a time.
2. Setting an entity reference when you don't want to update entities: This is a bad practice because if later code in the scope of that DbContext calls SaveChanges you're going to have FK errors or data being updated you didn't intend.
3. Returning entities, and the wrong entity: You don't want to return Ratings, you want to return Food. You should also avoid returning Entity objects from calls because this often includes far too much information about your schema, and you should *never* accept entities from the client code to do something like attach to a context and SaveChanges. It feels convenient and means less coding, but exposes your system to all kinds of unexpected/unintended updates.

To get what you want, you just need to leverage the relationship between ratings and food, select the relevant data into a ViewModel and return the view model.

ViewModel:

```
[Serializable]
public class FoodViewModel
{
    public int ID {get; set}
    public string Name {get; set}
    public decimal Price {get; set}
    public DateTime Date_Time" {get; set}
    public string FoodDescription {get; set}
    public string CookingTime {get; set}
    public string Uploadedby {get; set}
}
```

If you do need to return collections of details (Carts, FoodRecommendations, etc.) then define view models for these. As a general rule just return the data your view/consumer needs.

To select the food by descending rating:

```
var foodViewModels = db.Ratings.OrderByDescending(e => e.Rate)
    .Select(e => new FoodViewModel
    {
        ID = e.Food.ID,
        Name = e.Food.Name,
        Price = e.Food.Price,
        DateTime Date_Time = e.Food.Date_Time,
        FoodDescription = e.Food.FoodDescription,
        CookingTime = e.Food.CookingTime,
        UploadedBy = e.Food.UploadedBy
    }).Distinct().ToList();

return Request.HttpCreateResponse(foodViewModels);
```

As a guess, the relationship between food and ratings looks like a many-to-one where each food may have more than one rating so you will probably need to limit the results to only list the food by it's maximum rating. A `.Distinct()` may be enough before the `.ToList()`, either that or select from db.Foods and order by `.Max(f => Rating.Rate)`

I.e.:

```
var foodViewModels = db.Foods.OrderByDescending(f => f.Ratings.Max(r => r.Rate))
    .Select(f => new FoodViewModel
    {
        ID = f.ID,
        Name = f.Name,
        Price = f.Price,
        DateTime Date_Time = f.Date_Time,
        FoodDescription = f.FoodDescription,
        CookingTime = f.CookingTime,
        UploadedBy = f.UploadedBy
    }).ToList();
```